# Sampling after groupby while keeping all elements of a column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

MWE:

```
data = {'id': [0, 5, 6, 7, 1, 7, 1, 8, 2, 2, 3,3, 4, 5],
        'description':['0AAA', '0BBB', '0CCC', '0DDD',
                       '1EEE', '1FFF','1GGG', '1HHH',
                       '2III', '2JJJ','3KKK', '3LLL', '4MMM', '5NNN'],
        'cat':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

groupby by `cat` and select a maximum of `3` descriptions is easy.

```
def sampling(x: pd.Series, n: int, seed=1234):
    if len(x) <= n:
        return x
    else:
        return x.sample(n, random_state=seed)
# sampling
df_sampled = df.groupby(['cat']).apply(
    lambda x: sampling(x, n=3))

df_sampled.reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

What I want is to select a maximum of `3` descriptions while keeping all the different id.In the example above, we don't keep 8

Comment: It's unclear, what is the expected output? Do you want to ensure having all ids?

Comment: @mozway exact, All ids. Feel free to edit the question

Comment: @LearnToGrow What if number of unique ids are > 3 in a cat..What would be the desired output in such case?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, for sure, I want to keep all `ids` across the result not across each group